# Lambdas, multiple forEach with casting

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Need some help thinking in lambdas from my fellow StackOverflow luminaries.

Standard case of picking through a list of a list of a list to collect some children deep in a graph.  What awesome ways could `Lambdas` help with this boilerplate?

```
public List<ContextInfo> list() {
    final List<ContextInfo> list = new ArrayList<ContextInfo>();
    final StandardServer server = getServer();

    for (final Service service : server.findServices()) {
        if (service.getContainer() instanceof Engine) {
            final Engine engine = (Engine) service.getContainer();
            for (final Container possibleHost : engine.findChildren()) {
                if (possibleHost instanceof Host) {
                    final Host host = (Host) possibleHost;
                    for (final Container possibleContext : host.findChildren()) {
                        if (possibleContext instanceof Context) {
                            final Context context = (Context) possibleContext;
                            // copy to another object -- not the important part
                            final ContextInfo info = new ContextInfo(context.getPath());
                            info.setThisPart(context.getThisPart());
                            info.setNotImportant(context.getNotImportant());
                            list.add(info);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note the list itself is going to the client as `JSON`, so don't focus on what is returned.  Must be a few neat ways I can cut down the loops.

Interested to see what my fellow experts create.  Multiple approaches encouraged.

**EDIT**

The `findServices` and the two `findChildren` methods return arrays

**EDIT - BONUS CHALLENGE**

The "not important part" did turn out to be important.  I actually need to copy a value only available in the `host` instance.  This seems to ruin all the beautiful examples.  How would one carry state forward?

```
final ContextInfo info = new ContextInfo(context.getPath());
info.setHostname(host.getName()); // The Bonus Challenge
```

Comment: [Challenge accepted.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25439984/1441122)

Comment: [I accepted it first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25452763/1795426)

Answer (score 38):

It's fairly deeply nested but it doesn't seem exceptionally difficult.

The first observation is that if a for-loop translates into a stream, nested for-loops can be "flattened" into a single stream using `flatMap`. This operation takes a single element and returns an arbitrary number elements in a stream. I looked up and found that `StandardServer.findServices()` returns an array of `Service` so we turn this into a stream using `Arrays.stream()`. (I make similar assumptions for `Engine.findChildren()` and `Host.findChildren()`.

Next, the logic within each loop does an `instanceof` check and a cast. This can be modeled using streams as a `filter` operation to do the `instanceof` followed by a `map` operation that simply casts and returns the same reference. This is actually a no-op but it lets the static typing system convert a `Stream<Container>` to a `Stream<Host>` for example.

Applying these transformations to the nested loops, we get the following:

```
public List<ContextInfo> list() {
    final List<ContextInfo> list = new ArrayList<ContextInfo>();
    final StandardServer server = getServer();

    Arrays.stream(server.findServices())
        .filter(service -> service.getContainer() instanceof Engine)
        .map(service -> (Engine)service.getContainer())
        .flatMap(engine -> Arrays.stream(engine.findChildren()))
        .filter(possibleHost -> possibleHost instanceof Host)
        .map(possibleHost -> (Host)possibleHost)
        .flatMap(host -> Arrays.stream(host.findChildren()))
        .filter(possibleContext -> possibleContext instanceof Context)
        .map(possibleContext -> (Context)possibleContext)
        .forEach(context -> {
            // copy to another object -- not the important part
            final ContextInfo info = new ContextInfo(context.getPath());
            info.setThisPart(context.getThisPart());
            info.setNotImportant(context.getNotImportant());
            list.add(info);
        });
    return list;
}
```

But wait, there's more.

The final `forEach` operation is a slightly more complicated `map` operation that converts a `Context` into a `ContextInfo`. Furthermore, these are just collected into a `List` so we can use collectors to do this instead of creating and empty list up front and then populating it. Applying these refactorings results in the following:

```
public List<ContextInfo> list() {
    final StandardServer server = getServer();

    return Arrays.stream(server.findServices())
        .filter(service -> service.getContainer() instanceof Engine)
        .map(service -> (Engine)service.getContainer())
        .flatMap(engine -> Arrays.stream(engine.findChildren()))
        .filter(possibleHost -> possibleHost instanceof Host)
        .map(possibleHost -> (Host)possibleHost)
        .flatMap(host -> Arrays.stream(host.findChildren()))
        .filter(possibleContext -> possibleContext instanceof Context)
        .map(possibleContext -> (Context)possibleContext)
        .map(context -> {
            // copy to another object -- not the important part
            final ContextInfo info = new ContextInfo(context.getPath());
            info.setThisPart(context.getThisPart());
            info.setNotImportant(context.getNotImportant());
            return info;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I usually try to avoid multi-line lambdas (such as in the final `map` operation) so I'd refactor it into a little helper method that takes a `Context` and returns a `ContextInfo`. This doesn't shorten the code at all, but I think it does make it clearer.

**UPDATE**

But wait, there's still more.

Let's extract the call to `service.getContainer()` into its own pipeline element:

```
    return Arrays.stream(server.findServices())
        .map(service -> service.getContainer())
        .filter(container -> container instanceof Engine)
        .map(container -> (Engine)container)
        .flatMap(engine -> Arrays.stream(engine.findChildren()))
        // ...
```

This exposes the repetition of filtering on `instanceof` followed by a mapping with a cast. This is done three times in total. It seems likely that other code is going to need to do similar things, so it would be nice to extract this bit of logic into a helper method. The problem is that `filter` can change the number of elements in the stream (dropping ones that don't match) but it can't change their types. And `map` can change the types of elements, but it can't change their number. Can something change both the number and types? Yes, it's our old friend `flatMap` again! So our helper method needs to take an element and return a stream of elements of a different type. That return stream will contain a single casted element (if it matches) or it will be empty (if it doesn't match). The helper function would look like this:

```
<T,U> Stream<U> toType(T t, Class<U> clazz) {
    if (clazz.isInstance(t)) {
        return Stream.of(clazz.cast(t));
    } else {
        return Stream.empty();
    }
}
```

(This is loosely based on C#'s `OfType` construct mentioned in some of the comments.)

While we're at it, let's extract a method to create a `ContextInfo`:

```
ContextInfo makeContextInfo(Context context) {
    // copy to another object -- not the important part
    final ContextInfo info = new ContextInfo(context.getPath());
    info.setThisPart(context.getThisPart());
    info.setNotImportant(context.getNotImportant());
    return info;
}
```

After these extractions, the pipeline looks like this:

```
    return Arrays.stream(server.findServices())
        .map(service -> service.getContainer())
        .flatMap(container -> toType(container, Engine.class))
        .flatMap(engine -> Arrays.stream(engine.findChildren()))
        .flatMap(possibleHost -> toType(possibleHost, Host.class))
        .flatMap(host -> Arrays.stream(host.findChildren()))
        .flatMap(possibleContext -> toType(possibleContext, Context.class))
        .map(this::makeContextInfo)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Nicer, I think, and we've removed the dreaded multi-line statement lambda.

**UPDATE: BONUS CHALLENGE**

Once again, `flatMap` is your friend. Take the tail of the stream and migrate it into the last `flatMap` before the tail. That way the `host` variable is still in scope, and you can pass it to a `makeContextInfo` helper method that's been modified to take `host` as well.

```
    return Arrays.stream(server.findServices())
        .map(service -> service.getContainer())
        .flatMap(container -> toType(container, Engine.class))
        .flatMap(engine -> Arrays.stream(engine.findChildren()))
        .flatMap(possibleHost -> toType(possibleHost, Host.class))
        .flatMap(host -> Arrays.stream(host.findChildren())
                               .flatMap(possibleContext -> toType(possibleContext, Context.class))
                               .map(ctx -> makeContextInfo(ctx, host)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You could build an API from this alone... amazing work.

Comment: Since you are designing `toType` for exactly the application here, you could rewrite it as `<T,U> Function<T,Stream<U>> toType(Class<U> clazz) { return t -> { ... }; }` so that it can be invoked using just `.flatMap(toType(Engine.class))` without creating another anonymous lambda class.

Answer (score 26):

This would be my version of your code using JDK 8 streams, method references, and lambda expressions:

```
server.findServices()
    .stream()
    .map(Service::getContainer)
    .filter(Engine.class::isInstance)
    .map(Engine.class::cast)
    .flatMap(engine -> Arrays.stream(engine.findChildren()))
    .filter(Host.class::isInstance)
    .map(Host.class::cast)
    .flatMap(host -> Arrays.stream(host.findChildren()))
    .filter(Context.class::isInstance)
    .map(Context.class::cast)
    .map(context -> {
        ContextInfo info = new ContextInfo(context.getPath());
        info.setThisPart(context.getThisPart());
        info.setNotImportant(context.getNotImportant());
        return info;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this approach, I replace your if-statements for filter predicates. Take into account that an `instanceof` check can be replaced with a `Predicate<T>`

```
Predicate<Object> isEngine = someObject -> someObject instanceof Engine;
```

which can also be expressed as

```
Predicate<Object> isEngine = Engine.class::isInstance
```

Similarly, your casts can be replaced by `Function<T,R>`.

```
Function<Object,Engine> castToEngine = someObject -> (Engine) someObject;
```

Which is pretty much the same as

```
Function<Object,Engine> castToEngine = Engine.class::cast;
```

And adding items manually to a list in the for loop can be replaced with a collector. In production code, the lambda that transforms a `Context` into a `ContextInfo` can (and should) be extracted into a separate method, and used as a method reference.

Comment: Mind. blown. . . . all. over. the. floor.

Comment: The two `findChildren` methods return arrays.  How would you handle that?

Comment: I didn't. I may have missintepreted your code, the solution could be to map those to streams. Using something like `Arrays::stream` and possibly a `flatmap`. I don't know, this is just an idea on how to do it.

Comment: Not your fault on arrays, I didn't have that information in the questions when you answered.  Inspiring use of `Predicate`

Comment: Interesting use of method references for `Class::isInstance` and `Class::cast`.

Comment: from an FP perspective, mutating stuff and doing `list.add()` feels pretty wacky. From an OO perspective, while this example is clearly more readable than the OP's, it's still lagging far behind LINQ, where you would use `OfType<T>()` instead of that reflection thing.

Comment: @HighCore For more referential transparency, we could use a map lambda to create the context info and the terminal method would be `collect(Collectors.toList())` which can then be used to either do the mutation of the original list or simply replace it. Unfortunately the Streams API is still light years away from LINQ. Maybe in another 4 or 5 years :-)

Comment: @HighCore: fixed. Mapping and using a collector (as I've just seen Edwin Dalorzo suggest) is the side-effect free way of doing that.

Comment: You need to use `Stream.of` to convert `T[]` array to `Stream<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution to bonus challenge

Inspired by @EdwinDalorzo answer.

```
public List<ContextInfo> list() {
    final List<ContextInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final StandardServer server = getServer();

    return server.findServices()
            .stream()
            .map(Service::getContainer)
            .filter(Engine.class::isInstance)
            .map(Engine.class::cast)
            .flatMap(engine -> Arrays.stream(engine.findChildren()))
            .filter(Host.class::isInstance)
            .map(Host.class::cast)
            .flatMap(host -> mapContainers(
                Arrays.stream(host.findChildren()), host.getName())
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Stream<ContextInfo> mapContainers(Stream<Container> containers,
    String hostname) {
    return containers
            .filter(Context.class::isInstance)
            .map(Context.class::cast)
            .map(context -> {
                ContextInfo info = new ContextInfo(context.getPath());
                info.setThisPart(context.getThisPart());
                info.setNotImportant(context.getNotImportant());
                info.setHostname(hostname); // The Bonus Challenge
                return info;
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First attempt beyond ugly.  It will be years before I find this readable.  Has to be a better way.

Note the `findChildren` methods return arrays which of course work with `for (N n: array)` syntax, but not with the new `Iterable.forEach` method.  Had to wrap them with `Arrays.asList`

```
public List<ContextInfo> list() {
    final List<ContextInfo> list = new ArrayList<ContextInfo>();
    final StandardServer server = getServer();

    asList(server.findServices()).forEach(service -> {

        if (!(service.getContainer() instanceof Engine)) return;

        final Engine engine = (Engine) service.getContainer();

        instanceOf(Host.class, asList(engine.findChildren())).forEach(host -> {

            instanceOf(Context.class, asList(host.findChildren())).forEach(context -> {

                // copy to another object -- not the important part
                final ContextInfo info = new ContextInfo(context.getPath());
                info.setThisPart(context.getThisPart());
                info.setNotImportant(context.getNotImportant());
                list.add(info);
            });
        });
    });

    return list;
}
```

The utility methods

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> instanceOf(final Class<T> type, final Collection collection) {
    final Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();
    return () -> new SlambdaIterator<>(() -> {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Object object = iterator.next();
            if (object != null && type.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
                return (T) object;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    });
}
```

And finally a Lambda-powerable implementation of `Iterable`

```
public static class SlambdaIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    // Ya put your Lambdas in there
    public static interface Advancer<T> {
        T advance() throws NoSuchElementException;
    }
    private final Advancer<T> advancer;
    private T next;

    protected SlambdaIterator(final Advancer<T> advancer) {
        this.advancer = advancer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (next != null) return true;

        try {
            next = advancer.advance();

            return next != null;
        } catch (final NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();

        final T v = next;
        next = null;
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Lots of plumbing and no doubt 5x the byte code.  Must be a better way.

Comment: My first ever lambda.  Leaving here as a warning to everyone on what **not** to do.

Comment: This is an interesting illustration of the kind of code one might have to write if Java 8 had lambdas but **not** the Streams API.

Comment: I'll take it :)  I think it'll be a good reference on how Lambdas can be either used or abused. "This is why you need to learn the Streams API"