# functional interface unit testing

Tags: java, functional-interface

How do you test classes that are using functional interfaces. So how could i test the two concrete classes below:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Test {
    int sumTwoValues(int x, int y);
}


public class UseTestExample {

   public int useTest(int z, Test test) {
     int returnValue = test.sumTwoValues(z, 10);

     return returnValue;
   }

}


public class MainTest {

  public void clientCall() {
    UseTestExample testExample = new UseTestExample();
   
    testExample.useTest(10, (x,y) -> {
        return x+y;
    });
  }
}
```

I can see that UseTestExample, I could pass in an implementation during unit test and check what i get back is correct?

But the MainTest class, how would i be able to test that?

Comment: You're asking how to test the lambda defined in MainTest? If yes, check out e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28689737/12284870

Comment: why not simply `Assert.assertEquals(20, testExample.useTest(10, (x,y) -> {
        return x+y;
    }));` ?